# How can I remove all nodes in the node-red?

Tags: node-red

How can I remove all nodes in the node-red?

Right now I see only the option to remove the flows one by one by going to `Menu in top right corner` - `Flows` - `Delete`. That is not convenient at all, since I have a lot of flows to delete (more than 100) and I would like to do that in batch.

So, is the option to remove all flows absent or is it just hiding somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in option to remove all flows.

You can select multiple flows by Ctrl-Clicking on the tabs, then hit the 'delete' key on your keyboard to remove them.

If you really want to delete everything, you could delete your flow file and restart Node-RED.

Comment: How could I find out path to the flow file?

Answer (score 0):

As written [here](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/clear-everything-from-node-red/58152/3)

> So,
>
> If you want to delete node modules That is, something you have
> installed from the palette menu, you can go to the palette menu again
> and remove.
>
> If you want to delete a single flow double click the flow and choose
> delete
>
> If you want to delete a subflow double click the subflow and choose
> delete (along the top)
>
> If you want to nuke all flows/subflows
>
> ```
> Stop Node red
> Delete the flows file usually ~/.node-red/flows.json
> ```
>
> If you want to start fresh - I.e no flows/modules installed (a clean
> state) Just note: this will remove everything - it will be a clean
> state in Node RED
>
> ```
> Stop Node red
> Delete everything in ~/.node-red/
> ```

So in Linux you can remove all flows using the command

```
sudo rm -r ~/.node-red/flows.json
```